# REST + Facebook as authentication - best practice?

Tags: facebook, rest, session, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app that pulls data every 5 seconds from a REST api. In the most simple matter, the app pulls the Facebook user_token and uses it for authentication in the HTTP request. The REST api then checks up with Facebook and pulls data from the given token. Lastly, the data is processed, stored and returned to the client.

Now my question: is this a bad solution? If 10.000 users are connected, and every 5 seconds request data, my REST api would have 50.000 requests to Facebook every 5 seconds. It seems like a lot, but I researched that the limit of Facebook calls, per token, per IP is 600 every 600 seconds. Should I implement a session-based solution myself, and pull the data less frequent?

Oh, by the way: is this even secure? The user_token seem to rarely change, and if a person gets the user_token, he could request a lot of data on another user.

Best regards,

Comment: Why don't you use the Realtime Updates API? I think it doesn't necessarily make sense to pull the data every 5 secs...

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented the callback for certain updates, so I don't have to perform the same amount of requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That limit is just a recommendation, it depends on many factors and there is no static limit. As long as you are using User Tokens for all those Users, you should not have any problem.

Comment: Thanks! But to the bonus question: is the user_token a valid and secure way to ensure my users identity? I mean, the user_tokens seems to be valid for quite a while, and if a person obtains another persons user_token, he could easily request data on another users behalf.

Comment: not sure what you mean. the user token is the ONLY way to get the identity of a user...of course you need to keep tokens secret, but if you use one of the sdks, you don´t need to worry about tokens anyway in most cases. look up "appsecret_proof" in the docs too.